# Merge jq output into a comma separated string like

Tags: command-line, json, jq, prometheus-exporter

I have this output and would like to convert it into a Prometheus-like format by [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

`cat /tmp/wp-plugin.txt | jq  .[]`

```json
{
  "name": "akismet",
  "status": "active",
  "update": "none",
  "version": "5.0"
}
{
  "name": "performance-lab",
  "status": "active",
  "update": "none",
  "version": "1.4.0"
}
```

My goal is to get like this using JQ CLI tools

```json
wp_plugins{name="akismet",status="active",update="none",version="5.0"}0
wp_plugins{name="performance-lab",status="active",update="active",version="1.4.0"}1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | .key as $k | .value | to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value|@json)") | "wp_plugins{\(join(","))}\($k)"' file
```

or

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | .key as $k | .value | to_entries | "wp_plugins{\(map("\(.key)=\(.value|@json)")|join(","))}\($k)"' file
```

This takes your original JSON file and starts by turning each array entry into a key-value pair using `to_entries`.  The key will be the array index, and the value will be the actual object.

Since we want to create a comma-delimited key-value list with unquoted keys and quoted values, with `=` between each key and value, we need to process the `.value` (i.e. the object).  We do that by passing it through `to_entries` again to get a new list of keys and values.

The keys and values are then passed to a string constructor that composes the output in the format you are looking for, prepending the string `wp_plugins{` to the start of the comma-delimited list, appending `}` and the array index to the end.

The output, given the data in the question (when the data is put into an array first):

```
wp_plugins{name="akismet",status="active",update="none",version="5.0"}0
wp_plugins{name="performance-lab",status="active",update="none",version="1.4.0"}1
```

---

A corrected variant that uses a `0` at the end of the output line if the `update` key is not `available`, and `1` if it is `available`:

```bash
jq -r '
    to_entries[] |
    (if .value.update == "available" then 1 else 0 end) as $v |
    .value | to_entries |
    map("\(.key)=\(.value|@json)") | join(",") |
    "wp_plugins{\(.)}\($v)"' file
```

Comment: Kusalananda, thank you a lot. You saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko I realised that the first part of the answer is wrong as it creates the output on the wrong format (quoted keys and `:` in place of `=`).  I will delete that bit and clean everything up. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Amazing. May I ask you another question? :)
Is it possible using JQ to change at the end of a string wp_plugins{...}0 or 1, depending on "update": "none", then zero, if "update": "available", then one?

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko Ah, I thought the integer was from the order in the list. Yes, I will update my answer if you update the question to clarify where that integer comes from.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is really kind of magic!